# Pro Webmasters AKA the Dumping Ground - Flagging old Questions good or not?

Tags: discussion, support, suitable-question, moderators

I'm going though all unanswered questions and it just seems a hell lot of these questions are not even webmasters and in fact not suitable for any Stack Exchange Site. It would seem that people are just migrating it here because it doesn't fit on their stack.

My question is simple is it favorable to go though all old posts and flag ones that should be flagged for one reason or another? I know this is allowed but I don't want to upset mods with hundreds of reviews (currently at 45 flags daily) if they prefer not too ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't mind if you flag a bunch of them as being off-topic, low quality, etc. If they're a bad fit, they're a bad fit. And there's enough of us that it shouldn't be too much of a burden for anybody. If we find it becomes problematic for some reason we'll let you know.